# Performance regression upgrading Rails 2.3 to 5.2 and JRuby 1.7 to JRuby 9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, jruby

We have an app that was initially created in 2008 on Rails 2.3. This app runs on top of JRuby version 1.7, in Ruby 1.8 compatibility mode.

This is a largish app with 350 controllers and 450 models.

We're (finally) upgrading the app to Rails 5.2, upgrading JRuby to latest version 9.2.8.0.

We're now noticing a significant performance regression compared to the old app, running on the same server and database. Most requests are 30% to 200% slower than in the Rails 2.3 version.

The slowdown seems to be linear to the amount of data rendered. I.e. when we render a large table of data, the request may take 3000ms vs 1000ms on the old version, even when there is no DB access happening in the view. When rendering a request with little data, the slowdown is much less pronounced.

For instance, Rails 2.3 will render a certain "heavy" page in 3 sec:

`Completed in 2962ms (View: 1565, DB: 1384)`

Compared to 7 sec for the new version:

`Completed 200 OK in 7254ms (Views: 5808.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1389.3ms)`

The DB access time is very similar, but the "view" time is much much higher.

We've tried running our app on MRI Ruby, and it's 3 times faster than on JRuby 9. Unfortunately, we make extensive use of Java libraries in our code, so we can't easily switch to MRI.

Some questions:

Is JRuby still a viable option for Rails 5, is anyone using it with good performance?

I couldn't find a recommendation which JDK to run JRuby on. 
We're now running on OpenJDK 8. I've briefly tried OpenJDK 13 but that seemed even slower.
Is there a recommended version?

We're using these options: `JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Xmx4g -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=300M --server`.
Any recommendations on other options that may improve performance?

We've used "Datadog" to produce flame-graphs of our requests, which confirms that most of the time is spent rendering views outside of data access, but we can't really tell what is costing time in the view. We've tried attaching JVisualVM to the app in sampling mode, but it's very hard to get useful metrics out of this. Is there a better way of profiling JRuby on Rails applications?

Comment: Are you deploying/running on windows? This ticket seems related: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/5857

Comment: @nathanvda, no, we're deploying on Linux. Performance is comparable on Windows (running on my local machine in production mode)

Comment: Which library do you use to render the views: erb/haml/slim? If the above ticket was not relevant, I would propose opening a ticket on jruby github as they are very responsive.

Comment: @nathanvda We're using haml! I don't think it's basic haml issue, we can render a table with 10000 rows in 15ms. It's more a combination things like link_to and render :partial appearing to be "a bit" slower, adding up to slower request times. It's hard to file a bug report at JRuby for this, I think.